# Does every function in a Windows GUI application need to use stdcall?

Tags: c, winapi, calling-convention

From what I understand, the caller and the callee both need to have the same calling convention. Otherwise, the stack might be corrupted.

`WinMain` is declared with `__stdcall` and calls all the functions I've defined. Does this mean all the functions I define should use the `stdcall` calling convention?

I've tried not using `__stdcall` and nothing bad happened. I have also seen well-known GUI libraries supporting Windows don't use `stdcall`. Why is the stack not corrupting?

Comment: The caller and callee must agree on the callee's calling convention. It is common for the caller and callee to have different conventions themselves. You are probably doing it yourself already: All functions in the C standard library are cdecl but you can call them just fine from WinMain.

Comment: Calling conventions are a contract between callers and callees. If you call into libraries (like the Windows API) you have to follow the libraries' contracts. If you implement a library you get to decide which calling convention to use. If you target x64 things are less intricate: There's only one calling convention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> WinMain is declared with `__stdcall` and calls all the functions I've defined. Does this mean all the functions I define should use the `stdcall` calling convention?

No.  Calling conventions are handled on a per-function-call basis, right at the call site.  The convention dictates how the caller and callee manage the call stack - how parameters are passed, in what order, who cleans up the stack, etc.  As long as the caller and callee agree to use the same calling convention on each individual function call, it is perfectly safe for a `stdcall` function to call a function that uses a different convention, like `cdecl`, and vice versa.  A function's calling convention applies only when:

- the function is being entered by a new caller.
- the function is returning back to that caller.
- the function is accessing its own parameters.

Outside of that, what a function does internally has nothing to with its own calling convention.

For example, lets say that `WinMain()`, a `stdcall` function, wants to call a `cdecl` function.

It does not matter at all that `WinMain()` is itself a `stdcall` function.  While code execution is inside of `WinMain()`, it can do whatever it wants.  `WinMain()`'s `stdcall` convention is applied only upon entry and exit of `WinMain()` itself.  That is the contract `WinMain()` has with ITS caller.

What matters is that `WinMain()` must follow the rules of `cdecl` when setting up the call stack for a `cdecl` function that it is about to call into, and cleaning up the call stack when that function returns back to `WinMain()`.

The same goes for any function call of any calling convention.

> I've tried not using `__stdcall` and nothing bad happened. I have also seen well-known GUI libraries supporting Windows don't use `stdcall`. Why is the stack not corrupting?

Because the call stack is being managed correctly at every function call and return, so there is no unbalanced cleanup to corrupt the stack.

Comment: What makes calling conventions agree with each other? I initially thought they only agree when they have the same calling convention, but apparently not.

Comment: "*I initially thought they only agree when they have the same calling convention*" - that is exactly true. If the caller's declaration of a given function uses the same calling convention that the callee uses in the function's implementation, then things are good.  If the caller uses a different convention, then you run into problems. "*but apparently not*" - why would you think that?

Comment: stdcall and cdecl are both different calling conventions but they still agree with each other. I understand that they still agree when they have the same calling convention, but I don't understand why cdecl and stdcall agree with each other even though they're both different.

Comment: "*stdcall and cdecl ... still agree with each other*" - no, they don't, because the have different cleanup rules.  In `stdcall`, the *callee* cleans up the call stack.  In `cdecl`, the *caller* does the cleanup.  You are focusing too much on what convention the caller uses for ITS OWN stack frame, rather than on what convention the caller uses to CALL THE NEXT FUNCTION.  I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: @kurupreo: You seem to be thinking that "`WinMain` is `stdcall`, `printf` is `cdecl`, therefore if `WinMain` calls `printf` then caller = `stdcall` and callee = `cdecl`" and trying to substitute those into Remy's statement that "the caller and callee agree" to get "`stdcall` and `cdecl` agree".  **That's not how calling conventions work.**  `WinMain` being `stdcall` affects the `return` statements inside of `WinMain`.  It doesn't affect any of the rest of the function body.  It does also affect the (toolchain-provided) function that calls `WinMain`.

Comment: Functions that take a variable number of arguments in x86-32 must use the CDECL calling convention. For this, the `WINAPIV` macro exists.

Comment: To be perfectly accurate, the calling convention of a function does also affect the initial code in that function that copies parameters from wherever the caller placed them.  But that's it... parameter access and return.  The rest of the function body can do anything it wants including calls to functions with other conventions.